# How to add CustomView to my custom keyboard in android like GIF keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I am creating custom keyboard it is working fine with all the key's.

But in place of all key's i want to add a customview like GIF keyboard.

Custom view contains scrollview with buttons like below image.

[image]

> ------- For Keyboard with key's----

```html
@Override

public View onCreateInputView() {

     kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);

     keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);

     kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);

     kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);

     return kv;

}
```